# SQL 2008 FTS Track Changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a table with a FTS catalog on a SQL Server 2008 R2 CU5  that is set to track changes. This is failing to track data during the day causing lookup issues; the rows are in the table but not the FTS Catalog.

What is the most efficient way to identify the rows in my table that haven't been indexed so i can update them to get them picked up by the FTS track changes again for population in the index?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not had an answer this is what I am doing at the moment; I am not convinced this is the most efficient way but haven't figured a way to optimise it yet.

Find the table ID i am interested in

```
DECLARE @TableID INT, @Debug bit = 1
SELECT @TableID = id
FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'tblMyTableOfFacts'
```

set a table to get a list of all the indexed rows

```
DECLARE @MissingIndexValues TABLE (DocID INT, rowID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Using the built in index pull out a list of all the indexed rows

```
INSERT INTO @MissingIndexValues
EXEC sp_fulltext_keymappings @TableID
```